# psql trigger para update en unico campo tabla

Tags: postgresql

Tengo dos tablas simples:

```
CREATE TABLE nene(
id integer  primary key,
nombre character varying,
altaCasal integer);

CREATE TABLE actividades (
nen integer,
actividad character varying,
CONSTRAINT nen_fkey FOREIGN KEY (nen)
REFERENCES public.nene (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION);
```

y quiero hacer un trigger que cuando inserte algo en `actividades` me haga un `update` en `nene` en el campo `altaActividad` indicandome el numero de actividades a las que se apunta un niño, he generado una funcion y su `trigger` el problema es que cuando hago un `insert` me actualiza todo los campos, como puedo hacer que solo me actualize el id del niño al cual se le hace el insert?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.registre_actividades()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
declare
acti integer=0;
begin

IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN

update nene set altaCasal=(acti+1);
RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER Acti after INSERT ON actividades FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.registre_actividades();
```

Comment: Soy de oracle pero ya te digo que te falta el where en el "update nene" pasandole como parametro el id por el que ha saltado el trigger.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero como voy a pasar un parametro de una acción que aun no se ha ejecutado, quiero decir cuando se hace el insert puede ser cualquier id, eso no lo veo factible... se me esta ocurriendo ahora una opción seria recorrer la tabla con clave primaria nene y comparar el id que entra por el insert, voy a tirar por ahi, ahora toca pensar como comparar esos campos. Gracias igualmente